# My background image of the jsp is working fine in chrome but it is not fitting to screen in the jboss browser

Tags: html, css, eclipse, jsp, jboss

I don't have much idea on html/css.. I am developing a gift card app..But in the jsp page where the virtual gift card is displayed,the background image is working fine in chrome..but it is not fitting to the screen in my jboss browser.. The IDE I'm using is eclipse.. Here is my code.. I

```css
    .button {
      background-color: #color;
      border-bottom: solid;
      border-left: #FFEEEE;
      border-right: solid;
      border-top: #EEEEEE;
      color: Black;
      font-family: Verdana, Arial;
    }
    //this is the css for my body section
    body {
      background-image: url(images/back_stars.jpg);
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-position: top center !important;
      background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    table.card td {
      color: Black;
      font-family: "Myriad Web", Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-style: italic;
    }
```

```html
<html>

<body background="images/back_stars.jpg ">
  <div style='position: absolute; z-index: 0; left: 300px; top: 120px; width: 400px; height: 400px'>
    <img src='images/images (2).jpg' border=4 style='width: 400px; height: 300px' alt='[]' />
    <table class="card" style="top: 160px; width: 150px; left: 100px; position: absolute;">
      <% String Name=( String) request.getAttribute( "Name"); 
         String Card_no=( String) request.getAttribute( "Card_no"); 
         String Balance=( String) request.getAttribute( "Balance"); 
         String Expiry=( String) request.getAttribute( "Expiry_Date"); 
         out.print("<tr><td>" + " Name: "+ "</td>"); 
         out.print( "<td>" +Name+ "</td></tr>"); 
         out.print( "<tr>"); out.print( "<td>" + "Card No.: " + "</td>"); 
         out.print( "<td>" +Card_no+ "</td></tr>"); 
         out.print( "<tr><td>" + "Amount: "+ "</td>"); 
         out.print( "<td>" + Balance + "</td></tr>"); 
         out.print( "<tr><td>" + "Expiry: " + "</td>"); 
         out.print( "<td>" + Expiry + "</td></tr>"); %>
    </table>
    <form action="index.jsp">
      <table style="top: 360px; width: 50px; left: 180px; position: absolute;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="submit" value="HOME" class="button" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend testing in the types of browsers that your customers will be using. I am not sure what engine the JBoss Browser is using, but it sounds like it's not webkit... it's probably something proprietary and not adhering to a standard.

Comment: If you're using BrowserSim the engine is JavaFX which no one uses.